# Argument and Principle Argument of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Why in case of a complex number z=x+iy the principle argument is different from the general argument?

I got to know that the principle argument of the 
complex no.is from -pi to +pi

But the general argument is from 0 to 2pi. Why??

Is this true for any complex no.or only for a particular type of complex numbers??

Comment: It sounds like "general" argument and "principal" argument are two words for the same thing and that you read this from two different authors who had different opinions of where the [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) should be.  They are both equally valid choices.  Use whichever is more convenient for you at the time and make it clear which you are using when using it.  Each choice has their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Now... maybe "general argument" is not just another name for principal argument... but in that case it is probably the case that there is simply *no restriction* on the argument... You could have an argument well outside the range of 0 to 2pi, but that leads to confusion such as that $e^{2\pi i}=e^{4\pi i}$ and so if we wanted to talk about the square root of this, we might have been inclined to simply divide the exponent by two... but $e^{\pi i}\neq e^{2\pi i}$ despite the inputs being equal, so if we wanted the square root function to have one output per input we needed to be more careful.

Comment: So when there is an angle in the third quadrant, i should consider it as (pi+theta) or -(pi-theta). Both would lead to different answers.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about complex number, then the range of the principal argument of $\theta$ in:
$$z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$$
is in $[-\pi,\pi]$.

When the complex number is in the first or the second quadrant, then we have:
$$\theta\in[0,\pi]$$
When the complex number belongs to the thrid and fouth quadrant, we consider $\theta$ to be negative, or:
$$\theta\in[-\pi,0]$$
In fact this doesn't change the value of sine and cosine function. In particular:
$$\cos(-\phi)=\cos(\phi)$$
and:
$$\sin(-\phi)=-\sin(\phi)$$